# How to store and call a variable in PHP from an array

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using this script below that creates a random background image on a site. It has array items and appends them to the variable $selectedBg.

```
<?php
  $bg = array('background-1.jpg', 'background-2.jpg', 'background-3.jpg', 'background-4.jpg', 'background-5.jpg' ); // array of filenames
  $i = rand(0, count($bg)-1); //generate random number size of the array
  $selectedBg = "$bg[$i]"; // set variable equal to which random filename was chosen
?>
<style type="text/css">
body{
background: url(<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/backgrounds/<?php echo $selectedBg; ?>) no-repeat;
}
</style>
```

I would like to then take what is in $selectedBg, store it as a global variable to be used in other .php files in my wordpress isntallation, and do a switch case that creates different output for each variable from the array. Let's say if it is 'background-1.jpg' as the value for $selectedBg then I want to output text. If it is 'background-2.jpg' as the value for $selectedBg then I want to output different text, and so on.

How would I write the code that checks what is stored in $selectedBg? I'm getting lost trying to take

```
switch ($selectedBg) {
case "$selectedBg == 'background-1.jpg'":
echo "whatever";
break;
```

or the equivalent.

The reason why I'm making this global is I have the code in header.php, but I need to see what type of background is displayed on the page to output certain text. If it is background-1.jpg I want TEXT A; if background-2.jpg I want TEXT B; etc.

Comment: `"$bg[$i]"` is rather pointless. all you're doing is wrapping your value inside a string, which is redundant. why not just `$foo = $bg[$i]`?

Comment: 1) Just do: `$selectedBg = $bg[array_rand($bg)];` 2) Associative array: `Array ( "background-1,jpg" => "this text", ...)`

Comment: thank you so much; you are much smarter than i!

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see in your code, $selectedBg is not an array.

```
$i = rand(0, count($bg)-1); //generate random number size of the array
$selectedBg = "$bg[$i]";
```

$bg[$i] is a string.

Also, "$bg[$i]" in quotes is wrong. Should be:

```
$selectedBg = $bg[$i];
```

Your switch case syntax is wrong, should be:

```
switch ($selectedBg) {
    case 'background-1.jpg':
        echo "whatever";
    break;
}
```

Also acceptable:

```
switch (true) {
    case($selectedBg == 'background-1.jpg'):
        echo "whatever";
    break;
}
```

Switch (variable) matches case (variable).

PHP Documentation on [Switch](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php)

Comment: thank you for the help. this makes sense. however, i need to make the switch global so that i can call it later in the file. would you be able to offer advice to this?

Comment: Variable scope is kind of lengthy. Simply, if you assign a variable outside of a class method or function, it should be global already. If you need to use a global variable within a class method or function, first you need to call it via `global $varname, $varname2, $etc;` before you use it. Then through out the method or function, any value to assign to the global variable will be accessible globally. But in typical WP template setup, if you're assigning this value in the header.php and want to use it in page.php, you don't need to use `global` to do that.